# I am Indian, living in Kraków in Poland and have valid EU blue card. Can I travel back to India and come back?

Tags: visas, air-travel

I am Indian, living in Kraków in Poland, I have valid EU blue card. 
Can I travel back to India and come back?

My visa is expired, but EU blue card gives me the opportunity to stay in Poland at least untill 2021.

My concern is there will be a problem while coming back to Poland from India

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You of course need a valid Indian passport in addition to the documents you mentioned in your question, but I assume that you knew that and took it for granted.

Your blue card is a type of residence permit, and it should say as much on the card itself.  With a residence permit, you do not need any additional visa.  So the answer to your question is "yes," you can travel to India and return to Poland.